# MVC Get Basic RadioButton checked properties through form collection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

had this code in my view . The usual radio list code without helper

```
        <br /><input type="radio" name="radioFree" id="radioFree" value="Free" checked="checked"  />
        <br /><input type="radio" name="radioDiscount" id="radioDiscount" value="Discount" />
```

And then in the controller , I have

```
     public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
     {
         return View();
     }
```

How do I get which radio is checked , using the form ? Collection["radioFree"] only gave me back the radio's value . Thanks .

### Solved by author

Use helpers in View

```
    <br />@Html.RadioButton("DiscountType", "Free")
    <br />@Html.RadioButton("DiscountType", "Discount")
```

then determine the value helpers returned from collection .

Comment: I reverted your edit to show the original question and added your answer to the end of it.  Ideally you should add your answer as an answer and then mark it as the correct one.  In the future if people search for a similar topic they won't see that this question has an accepted answer otherwise.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.Net MVC: Can I use a FormCollection to determine which radio button was selected?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911679/asp-net-mvc-can-i-use-a-formcollection-to-determine-which-radio-button-was-sele)

Answer (score 2):

You should give both Radio buttons the same name (form name - ID can be different) and then either use the value provider, or straightforward binding.  You ideally want to map the group of radios to one value.

```
<input type="radio" name="radioValue" id="radioFree" value="Free" checked="checked"  />            
<input type="radio" name="radioValue" id="radioDiscount" value="Discount" />
```

Binding:

```
public ActionResult Index(string radioValue)
{
  if(radioValue == "Free")
  {

  }
  else id(radioValue == "Discount")
  {

  }
}
```

You can also do this:

```
string radioValue = null;
var valueResult = ValueProvider.GetValue("radioValue");
if (valueResult != null)
{
  radioValue = valueResult.AttemptedValue;
}
```